# What is the significance of a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the difference between doing this:

```
int i = 5, j = 6, k = 7;
int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;



int *ipp = ip1;
```

and doing this:

```
int **ipp2 = &ip1;
```

Don't they do the same thing? hold a pointer(ip1) which points to a variable, i?

Comment: No, the second points to `ip1`.

Comment: One's an `int *` and the other is an `int **` -- what do you mean by "do the same thing"? They aren't even the same type.

Comment: what is ipp doing then if it isn't pointing to ip1?

Comment: `ipp` is pointing to `i`, not `ip1`. It was initialized using `ip1` and `ip1` was pointing to `i` at the time of the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the variables have a location in memory where their values are held. Let's explore the relationships between the values of `i`, `ip1`, `ipp`, and `ipp2`

This is what you get when the statement `i = 5;` is executed. `i` has its location in memory and the value at location is set to `5`.

```
i ->     +--------+
         |  5     |
         +--------+
         ^
         |
         A1 (address of i)
```

This is what you get when the statement `int* ip1 = &i;` is executed. `ip1` has its location in memory and the value at that location is set to the address of `i`, which we designate as `A1`.

```
ip1 ->   +--------+
         |   A1   |
         +--------+
         ^
         |
         A2 (address of ip1)
```

This is what happens when you execute the statement `int* ipp = ip1;`. The value at the memory location of `ipp` is set to the value of `ip1`, which is `A1`.

```
ipp ->   +--------+
         |   A1   |
         +--------+
         ^
         |
         A3 (address of ipp)
```

This is what happens when you execute the statement `int** ipp2 = &ipp;`. The value at the memory location of `ipp2` is set to `A3`, which is the address of `ip1.

```
ipp2 ->  +--------+
         |   A3   |
         +--------+
         ^
         |
         A4 (address of ipp2)
```

How does dereferencing work:

```
*ip1 = *A1 = 5
*ipp = *A1 = 5
*ipp2 = *A3 = A1
**ipp2 = **A3 = *A1 = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`ipp2` points to `ip1`. This is entirely different from pointing to `i`.

Sample code:

```
int *ip1 = &i;
int **ipp2 = &ip1;
printf("%d\n", **ipp2);    // 5
ip1 = &j;
printf("%d\n", **ipp2);    // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are often used to change the value of a variable inside a function:

```
void incr(int *ip) { *ip++; } 
void f() { int i = 0; incr(&i); printf("%d\n", i); // 1
```

Now it's not any different with a pointer to a pointer. You can pass the pointer to a pointer to a function, and that function can change what that pointer points to: *the original pointer!*

```
char *mom = "mom";
char *pop = "pop";
chooseMomOrPop(int choosePop, char **momOrPop) { *momOrPop =  choosePop ? pop : mom; }
void f() { char *mp = mom; chooseMomOrPop(1, &mom); printf("%s\n", mom); } // pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: a pointer is an address where a variable stays in memory. Since a pointer is itself a variable, its address could be stored in another pointer, and so on. To better have in mind how a pointer is and how it works, just think it is an address. The type of the pointer, ie `int` in `int *` refers to the type of the data pointed, and effect how the pointer "react" to addition or subtraction, as described in pointer arithmetic. A 'pointer to pointer of int' is an `int**`, so is always an address pointing to an `int*`, and when incremented it will move the address to as many byte as necessary to point the next `int*`